# Why can't I invoke click on the column menu button in kendo grid for Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, click, kendo-grid, invoke

I'm not sure if this is an issue with the column menu in Kendo grid for Angular or I'm just invoking click on a button element wrong.

What we're trying to do is move the column menu button out of the top section of the grid and into the column header row, like this:

[image]

After searching for a way to do this with Kendo Grid for Angular and finding nothing, I decided to create my own button, set its position to absolute, and set its position to where we want it (just like in the image above). Then the click event handler for my button would find the original grid button and invoke click() on it. I swear to God I had it working earlier, but now it's not working at all.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
    <div class="mtx-col-menu-btn" (click)="columnMenuButtonClick()">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    
    ...
    
    <ng-template kendoGridToolbarTemplate>
      <kendo-grid-column-chooser id="columnChooser"></kendo-grid-column-chooser>
    </ng-template>
```

CSS:

```
.mtx-col-menu-btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 73px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    z-index: 10;
    cursor: pointer;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;

    div {
        height: 13px;
        width: 4px;
        background-color: black;
    }
}
```

Typescript:

```
  public columnMenuButtonClick(): void {
    const columnMenuButton = document.querySelector('#columnChooser button');
    (columnMenuButton as HTMLElement).click();
  }
```

Either the click event isn't bringing up the column chooser in the correct way (or at all) or this is the wrong way to invoke a button click in Typescript/Javascript. It's a simple button element and I would think calling click() on it isn't a problem. So I suspect there's something about the column chooser that's blocking it from showing up (like it's positioned off the screen or maybe z-index is less than that of the grid).

You might also note I had to cast the columnMenuButton in the button handler to HTMLElement in order for Typescript to accept that it has a click() handler. But I noticed that even after casting it as an HTMLElement, no click() method exists when I hover over it. I don't know if this is just a shortcoming of the Chrome dev tools (wouldn't be the first time) or a button HTMLElement actually doesn't have a click() method (which can't be right as I've seen it done tons of times before):

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

UPDATE:

I discovered that the column chooser DOES come up in response to calling click() but I have to have a breakpoint set right after the call. That way, the application is paused and I see this:

[image]

Then when I step to the next line, it's gone. Without the breakpoint, I guess it all happens before it can be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: clicking the new button means clicking outside (or not on) the column menu, which was being processed as a trigger to close the menu. So I would open the menu programmatically in response to the button click, then the click event would propagate through, and the be processed as a "click outside menu" event. The key was to call event.stopPropagation().